# Separar en R una columna en múltiples según condición

Tags: r, dataframe

Me gustaría dividir en R una columna en varias según determinadas condiciones.

Por ejemplo, si el valor empieza por P irá a una columna y si empieza por F o C irá a otras columnas.

```
df <- data.frame(
  "name" = c("a", "b"),
  "ID" = c("P_GO_10;C_GO_23;C_GO_32", "P_GO_65;F_GO15;C_GO_97;F_GO_87"))

  name   ID
1    a P_GO_10;C_GO_23;C_GO_32
2    b P_GO_65;F_GO15;C_GO_97;F_GO_87
 

df_new <- data.frame(
  "name" = c("a", "b"),
  "ID_P" = c("P_GO_10", "P_GO_65"),
  "ID_C" = c("C_GO_23;C_GO_32","C_GO_97"),
  "ID_F" = c(NA, "F_GO_87"))

  name ID_P     ID_C               ID_F
1    a P_GO_10  C_GO_23;C_GO_32    <NA>
2    b P_GO_65  C_GO_97            F_GO_87
```

Answer (score 3):

Si usas `tidyverse` puede hacer algo así:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = strsplit(as.character(ID), ";")) %>% 
  unnest(ID) %>% 
  mutate(col=substr(ID, 1, 1)) %>%
  group_by(name, col) %>% 
  summarise(valores = paste0(ID, sep=";", collapse=""), .groups = "keep") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, 
              names_prefix = "ID_",
              values_from = valores) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  name  ID_C             ID_P     ID_F           
  <chr> <chr>            <chr>    <chr>          
1 a     C_GO_23;C_GO_32; P_GO_10; NA             
2 b     C_GO_97;         P_GO_65; F_GO15;F_GO_87;
```

Explicación:

1. Primero separamos con `strsplit()` todos los valores de la columna `ID` y expandimos estos usando `unnest(ID)` en nuevas filas.
2. Recuperamos la letra que le correspondería a cada valor con  `mutate(col=substr(ID, 1, 1))`
3. Agrupamos por el nombre y la letra, para concatenar nuevamente los valores que si deben ir juntos
4. Por último pasamos de una estructura larga a una ancha, mediante `pivot_wider()`